# How to determine for a T test, if we have paired or independent groups?

Tags: t-test

Could we have two answers to the same question?

For example, if we refer to the comparison between the same variable that is measured in two different places, it seems clear that we are talking about paired samples.

However, if we refer to the same data as two different variables, they would be independent samples.

What should we take into account in the definition of these variables to determine if they are truly paired or independent?

Comment: Short answer for paired testing: every member of group A has to have an unambiguous matching member in group B and the same construct was measured for both groups

Comment: @MrPi It is a particular case, with a study of a single person.
However, here the person is not the important thing, it is simply useful for driving a motorcycle. That is to say, we assume that the individual characteristics of that person do not condition the results of the measured variable.

Comment: @MrPi The variable measured is the vibration of the motorcycle, which is measured in an indoor circuit and in another outdoor circuit. However, the measurement protocol is completely different indoor than outdoor, with indoor completing complete laps of a circuit and outdoor measuring two sections, one going and one returning.
Since the basis of the protocol is so different, indoor and outdoor could be considered as independent groups.

Comment: Two different variables wouldn't be independent samples t-test. Independent samples t-test would be DIFFERENT PEOPLE on variable Y, whereas paired samples would be SAME PEOPLE on variable Y.

Comment: @JE52 The concept is the same, but how calculated is different.

Answer (score 2):

On the off chance you haven't seen it, it's worth considering what independence is.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)#For_real_valued_random_variables

> What should we take into account in the definition of these variables to determine if they are truly paired or independent?

Loosely, if there's another specific member in the other group whose value should tend to be more like this one than it would be (on average) if you replaced it with a random member of the other group, that's paired.

As a result, the variance of the within-pair difference in paired data tends to be smaller than the variance of the difference of two randomly selected values from each group.

If you could notionally replace some putative paired value with a randomly chosen other one without changing anything, you would often tend to treat it as independent (though strictly speaking that's a form of *exchangeability* rather than independence; if you have the first but not the second that means you have a particular kind of dependence that you're not accounting for, but going into that would get away from the specific distinction you're after here)